# how to get of names of files selected in FileReferenceList class

Tags: actionscript-3

i am working with FileReferenceList class to create a mutilpe image uploader
i forget how to get names of files select with browse method
i wante ask a question how to get a array of names  selected files to ste in array for datagrid column.
thanck you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileReferenceList` has a `fileList` array that contains `FileReference` objects for the selected files. You can get the file names using the `name` property of the `FileReference` class. Use the `frList.fileList` as the `dataProvider` of the `DataGrid` and then assign `"name"` to the `labelField` of the column.